# Angular 2+, How to read environment variable in module (webpack)

Tags: angular

I'm initializing my APP_INITIALIZER in app.module.browser.ts but I don't know how to read my environment variable.

```
  @NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppModuleShared,
    AppAuthModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl },
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER, // <-- HERE
      useFactory: configurationServiceFactory,
      deps: [ConfigurationService],
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor, //AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
    ConfigurationService,
    ErrorLogService
  ]
```

After initializing, I have some constant variables. I need to read my environment variable to determine the condition to import my module.

```
import { AccountsComponent } from "./customerList/components/accounts/accounts.component";
import { AccountsPlusComponent } from "./customerList/components/accounts-plus/accounts-plus.component";
    
let accountsInjection: any = ENV_VARIABLE ? AccountsComponent : AccountsPlusComponent;
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        accountsInjection
      ],
      imports: [
    ...
```

NOTE: I don't have an app/environment/ folder in my project... (I'm still looking for a way to generate one). I'm using Webpack atm, may I switch to another method for this operation?

Comment: Inside src create a folder environments. After that create the two files one with name **environment.prod.ts** and another one with name **environment.ts**. Then you store the variables in a const object called environment which has production key as false and true respectively. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382142/change-url-from-service-when-build-angular-6-project/51382330#51382330

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I have another environment, like 1.Production 2.Staging 3.StagingPlus, do you have any advice for this ?

Comment: Yes. you create a file called environment.stagingPlus.ts for instance having again production key as false, and then you  build it it via ng build --prod -c custom_environment_name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to save global settings in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44150172/where-to-save-global-settings-in-angular-4)

Comment: I've added extra information to topic, please do not ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the case if you want to access variable as env.variable_name

Dotenv is a zero-dependency module that loads environment variables.

Install:

```
npm install dotenv
```

Create a `.env` file in the root directory of your project. Add environment-specific variables on new lines in the form of `NAME=VALUE`. For example:

```
apiUrl= 'url'
enviorement= 'dev'
```

in component

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

use variables as :

```
process.env.appUrl,
```

Comment: I've added extra information to topic, please do not ignore.

Comment: just create it as src/enviorement/enviorement.ts and  src/enviorement/enviorement.prod.ts and export from it. try this if not working i will give you one more solution.

Comment: I've created environment.ts, environment.prod.ts, environment.staging.ts and environment.stagingPlus.ts ... How can I manage these files? I'm still looking for a solution to get env.variable from webpack...

Answer (score 0):

This is for angular 6. But we can have similar configuration in angular >2 as well .
Angular.json

```
 "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ]
           },
"test": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
```

Similarly for other environments.

Package.json -

```
  "start": "ng serve --configuration=dev",
    "prod": "ng serve --configuration=prod",
    "test": "ng serve --configuration=test",
```

In Component -

```
import { environment } from '/../environments/environment'; // as per your path

//use like

environment.property_name
```